# Delphi IDE - Command line switches and explanation

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe

where I can get a Delphi XE list of command line switches to startup bds (delphi) ?

For the moment, I know this:

-pDelphi -> when use it ?  (install default)
-nocache -> when use it

But I can startup bds without any of them.  Even the default: -pDelphi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These switches are documented: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/IDE_Command_Line_Switches_and_Options

Comment: A poor documentation.  -nocache switch is not there.  Personality values are a bit confusing.  But it is a documentation at least.  Thanks.

Comment: @FerPt - `-nocache` is IMHO undocumented one; [here is](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/IDE_Command_Line_Switches) another, unofficial list